# Importing GUIDs from CSV file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How would I import GUIDs from a CSV file? The guids are already in the `0x` format, like `0x10A82EE168F7D211BB8D11A0C9D56DCE`.

When I do this:

```
if object_id ('Zones' , 'U' ) is not null
      drop table Zones;
go

create table Zones
(
    ID binary(16) not null
    , Country varchar (100) not null
)

bulk
insert Zones
from '\\...\zones.csv'
with
(
    fieldterminator = ','
    , rowterminator = '\n'
)

go
```

I get the error:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me only when I stripped the `0x` prefix off the hexadecimal representations in the CSV file. The [manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) does not seem to offer any way to make the BULK INSERT statement recognise the prefix.

As a workaround, I would suggest importing the GUIDs first into a `char(34)` column and later convert it with `CONVERT(binary(16), CharID, 1)`.

Depending on whether `Zones` is meant to be just a staging table or the final destination for the imported data, you could either change the type of its `ID` column or use a temporary storage to directly bulk insert the data into and later insert from it into `Zones` with conversion.

Answer (score -1):

To store a GUID in a table, use the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type

Comment: That's not it. I changed binary(16) to uniqueidentifier and there are still errors.